# Cauchy's induction principle

Tags: induction

Cauchy's induction principle states that:

> The set of  propositions  $p(1),...,p(n),...$ are all  valid if:
>
> 1. $p(2)$ is true.
> 2. $p(n)$ implies  $p(n-1)$ is true.
> 3. $p(n)$ implies $p(2n)$ is true.

How  to prove  Cauchy's induction principle? Can we use it to  prove what we  can prove with weak  and strong induction?

If yes how  to  prove using Cauchy's induction principle

$$ 1+2^1+2^2+...+2^n=2^{n+1}-1 $$

Comment: Base case : $p(2)$ i.e. $1+2^1+2^2=2^{2+1}-1$.

Comment: Step 2 : Assume $p(n)$, i.e. $1+2^1+ \ldots + 2^n=2^{n+1}-1$ and prove that $1+2^1+ \ldots + 2^{n-1}=2^{n+1}-1-2^n=2^{n}-1$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738679/prove-x-is-a-partition-of-%E2%84%95-and-that-x-%E2%84%95) is closely related.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tilde p(n):=p(2^n)$. Then $\tilde p(1)=p(2)$ is true, and from $2^{n+1}=2\cdot 2^n$ it follows from your axiom $(3)$ by ordinary  induction that $\tilde p(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 1$.

Let an $n\geq1$ be given. It is a fundamental principle of mathematics that $n<2^n$, i.e., $n=2^n-j$ for some $j\geq1$. Let $p'(k):=p(2^n-k)$ when $k<2^n$ and $:={\tt true}$ when $k\geq2^n$. Then $p'(0)=p(2^n)=\tilde p(n)$ is true, hence $p'(k)$ is true  for all $k\geq0$ by your axiom $(2)$, in particular for $k=j$.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ denotes a well ordening on $\mathbb N$ then $R$ can be used for induction.

There will be an $n_0\in\mathbb N$ that serves as minimal element, and there will be a successor function $S:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ in the sense that $S(n)$ is according to $R$ the smallest element of $\mathbb N$ with $(n,S(n))\in R$.

Then a set of propositions $p(1),p(2),\dots$ is true if $p(n_0)$ is true and if $p(n)\implies p(S(n))$ is true.

Now observe that $\mathbb N$ can be well ordered according to:$$2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,12,11,\dots$$

So we have $n_0=2$, $S(2)=1$, $S(1)=4$ et cetera.

Then what is stated by Cauchy's induction principle is equivalent with:

- $p(n_0)$ is true
- $p(n)\implies p(S(n))$ is true.

So this shows that Cauchy's induction principle is indeed valid.